# Showing Flash-messages with loop vs using if-exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between showing flash-messages using ...

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <%= msg %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

... and using ...

```
<% if notice %>
  <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>
```

?

I have tried both pattern and both worked.

Why is 'notice' as variable in the second case? In the first case it's a dictionary.

**What happens there (in the second case)? Why doesn't have it to be unpacked?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from the [`Ruby on Rails documentation`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-notice):

> `notice()`
>
> Convenience accessor for `flash[:notice]`.
>
> ```
> # File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb, line 271
> def notice
>   self[:notice]
> end
> ```

Comment: I guess I will accustom to optional parenthesis, when calling a function/method in Ruby. Question to the more experienced Ruby-developers: Don't you consider it confusing, that isn't clear what it is? A function-invocation or a variable-name?

Comment: I was never confused by that, and I haven't worked with any app or team that required to write the optional parenthesis.